# How can I remove permissions programmatically in Java

Tags: java, security, permissions, jvm

I want to write a program in java that removes its own permissions and then, using ClassLoader, loads a unstrusted .class and invokes one of its methods.
How can I do this without messing with policy files, using only code.

Comment: What permissions are you talking about? What policy files?

Comment: If you want to load a class during runtime there are a lot of answered questions on StackOverflow

Comment: @aleb2000
The issue is not loading the class, that is already done .
 What I would like to know is how I can set the JVM permissions (deny reflection , socket use or file reading/writing) in runtime .

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html

Comment: @aleb2000
I've read that doc however, unless i'm completely misreading it, i can only give permissions not revoke them.

Comment: I think what you have to do is to set a custom policy file, take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html

Comment: I don't think it is possible with only code as the policy for the security manager is given at the start of the program by the JVM

Comment: @aleb2000
It really seems like it's impossible avoiding making a custom policy file.
thanks for the answer!

Comment: if you got a fully privileged JVM you can implement a securitymanager and load it at runtime